# Javascript - make html/bootstrap button active by function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button group that on click gets background color of blue:

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical answers_group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button button type="button" onclick="setArrayAnswer('optionA')" id="optionA" class="text-left btn text-secondary border border-info" data-toggle="button">
         <h3 class="text-primary">A.</h3>
         <p id="optionA_text" class="text-secondary text-left"></p>
     </button>
     <button button type="button" onclick="setArrayAnswer('optionB')" id="optionB" class="text-left btn text-secondary border border-info" data-toggle="button">
         <h3 class="text-primary">B.</h3>
         <p id="optionB_text" class="text-secondary text-left"></p>
     </button>
     <button button type="button" onclick="setArrayAnswer('optionC')" id="optionC" class="text-left btn text-secondary border border-info" data-toggle="tab">
         <h3 class="text-primary">C.</h3>
         <p id="optionC_text" class="text-secondary text-left"></p>
     </button>
     <button button type="button" onclick="setArrayAnswer('optionD')" id="optionD" class="text-left  btn text-secondary border border-info" data-toggle="button">
         <h3 class="text-primary">D.</h3>
         <p id="optionD_text" class="text-secondary text-left"></p>
     </button>
</div>
```

Now when the user click a button i store in an array a status of which answer he chose above. What i try to achieve is when a question gets loaded if it has already been answered i want to have the same effect as when i click it which i achieve like this:

```
.btn:focus {
    background: #81d4fa;
}
```

I tried with the following JS code:

```
var answer_id = "option" + subject1_arr[subject1_question].answer;
document.getElementById(answer_id).click();
```

Basically i just try to click the item depending on the ID which i get by concatenating the base id for all and adding the appropriate letter, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please include all relevant code we can't see the setArrayAnswer function and storage array.

Comment: Those functions are irrelevant to this they just set a status of answered which i check before executing the JS code from above and have no other funciton

Comment: @KristijanStefanoski *"Basically i just try to click the item depending on the ID which i get by concatenating the base id for all and adding the appropriate letter, but it doesn't work."*  This implies that `setArrayAnswer()` is the key to your issue. If you are so certain of what is relevant and what is not, then you should have no problem finding a solution on your own.

Comment: How does it actually imply that ? I tried console logging the id and its working, different methods also work only this one ?